# Send POST request with Python that generates a download and download the file

Tags: python, rest, post

There's a website that has a button which downloads an Excel file. After I click, it takes around 20 seconds for the server API to generate the file and send it back to my browser for download.

If I monitor the communication after I click the button, I can see how the browser sends a POST request to a server with a series of headers and form values.

[image: Snapshot of the form data]

Is there a way that I can simulate a similar POST request programmatically using Python, and retrieve the Excel file after the server sends it over?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests module is used for sending all kinds of request types.

`requests.post` sends the post requests synchronously.
The payload data can be set using `data=`
The response can be accessed using `.content`.
Be sure to check the `.status_code` and only save on a successful response code

Also note the use of "wb" inside open, because we want to save the file as a binary instead of text.

Example:

```py
import requests

payload = {"dao":"SampleDAO",
           "condigId": 1,
           ...}

r = requests.post("http://url.com/api", data=payload)

if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("file.save","wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

[Requests Documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll review the documentation right away. 

One question that I have is how can I know what the payload is supposed to be? I've monitored the request using postman and there's 14 Headers (host, user-agent, etc...), and a bunch of Body key-value pairs (X-XSRF-TOKEN, filter, exporter, etc...)

Comment: An HTTP requests consists of headers and a body, the headers are at the top of a request and seperated by the body with two newlines [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example). The payload is the raw text data at the end of the request.
Headers can be set via `headers={"header1":"value1"}`

Comment: If the key-value pairs are in plain text, you should be able to send them like that. IE `data="X-XSRF-TOKEN: AAA\nfilter:abc"`

Comment: got it, so when I make the requests I have to pass two separate parameters? requests.post("http://url.com/api", data=payload, headers=headers)

Comment: @ortunoa Correct :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess You could similarly do this:

```
file_info = request.get(url)

with open('file_name.extension', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(file_info.content)
```

I honestly do not know how to explain this tho since I have little understanding how it works

Comment: Yeah but there is form data that I'd like to send with the POST request, this data includes the "Start Date" and "End Date" that will be used to generate the Excel export

Comment: well try applying the same logic, otherwise I have no idea, however You would still get a link after You POST